Return the name of a column which matches a date value
I have a data.frame with about 66k rows and 150 columns. For the purposes of this question, this is a sample. All columns are date objects.
structure(list(fixed_date = structure(c(19267, 19239, 19120, 
18035, 19253, 19211, 19120, 19778, 19120, 19211, 18224, 18224, 
19624, 19211, 19211, 19211, 18409, 18409, 18558, 19876, 19267
), class = "Date"), BEGIN1 = structure(c(19240, 19212, 19086, 
18008, 19240, 19177, 19086, 19751, 19086, 19177, 18197, 18197, 
19597, 19177, 19177, 18197, 18197, 18197, 18477, 18477, 19240
), class = "Date"), END1 = structure(c(19267, 19239, 19120, 18035, 
19253, 19211, 19120, 19778, 19120, 19211, 18224, 18224, 19624, 
19211, 19211, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18488, 18488, 19267), class = "Date"), 
    BEGIN2 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18043, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18232, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18232, 18232, 18232, 18232, 18512, 19849, 
    18484), class = "Date"), END2 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18070, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18280, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18280, 18280, 
    18280, 18280, 18523, 19876, 18495), class = "Date"), BEGIN3 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 18897, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18323, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    18354, 18354, 18396, 18396, 18547, 19793, 18519), class = "Date"), 
    END3 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18924, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18350, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18381, 18381, 18409, 18409, 18558, 19827, 
    18530), class = "Date"), BEGIN4 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18113, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18687, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18722, 18372, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 18554), class = "Date"), END4 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 18140, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18700, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    18749, 18399, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18565), class = "Date"), BEGIN5 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 18148, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18407, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    18407, 18407, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), END5 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 18175, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18434, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    18434, 18434, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

What I want is a column that gives me the name of the column across columns 2 and 11 which is equal to the value of column 1. This runs with no errors but no column is created:
sample$match_date_<- apply(sample[,c(2:11)], 1, 
        function(x) names(which(x == sample[,1])))  

I don't know why this isn't working as expected and also I want to achieve a faster solution since I guess using apply will be slow. Any advice will be much appreciated.

As a tidyverse / dplyr package user, my suggestion is to use the column names as "variable" for easier manipulations, with pivot_longer(). If you anticipate that there will be a single match on every row, you can use filter(). I don't think that it will slow, some seconds on bigger dataset maybe.
library(tidyverse) 

df = structure(list(fixed_date = structure(c(19267, 19239, 19120, 
                                             18035, 19253, 19211, 19120, 19778, 19120, 19211, 18224, 18224, 
                                             19624, 19211, 19211, 19211, 18409, 18409, 18558, 19876, 19267
), class = "Date"), BEGIN1 = structure(c(19240, 19212, 19086, 
                                         18008, 19240, 19177, 19086, 19751, 19086, 19177, 18197, 18197, 
                                         19597, 19177, 19177, 18197, 18197, 18197, 18477, 18477, 19240
), class = "Date"), END1 = structure(c(19267, 19239, 19120, 18035, 
                                       19253, 19211, 19120, 19778, 19120, 19211, 18224, 18224, 19624, 
                                       19211, 19211, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18488, 18488, 19267), class = "Date"), 
BEGIN2 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18043, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18232, 
                     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18232, 18232, 18232, 18232, 18512, 19849, 
                     18484), class = "Date"), END2 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18070, 
                                                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18280, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18280, 18280, 
                                                                 18280, 18280, 18523, 19876, 18495), class = "Date"), BEGIN3 = structure(c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                           NA, 18897, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18323, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                           18354, 18354, 18396, 18396, 18547, 19793, 18519), class = "Date"), 
END3 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18924, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18350, 
                   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18381, 18381, 18409, 18409, 18558, 19827, 
                   18530), class = "Date"), BEGIN4 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18113, 
                                                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18687, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18722, 18372, 
                                                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, 18554), class = "Date"), END4 = structure(c(NA, 
                                                                                                                             NA, 18140, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18700, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                             18749, 18399, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18565), class = "Date"), BEGIN5 = structure(c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA, 18148, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18407, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         18407, 18407, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), END5 = structure(c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                NA, 18175, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18434, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                18434, 18434, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df %>% mutate(id = 1:n() ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(fixed_date, id) )  %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(fixed_date ==value)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [20]
#>    fixed_date    id name  value     
#>    <date>     <int> <chr> <date>    
#>  1 2022-10-02     1 END1  2022-10-02
#>  2 2022-09-04     2 END1  2022-09-04
#>  3 2022-05-08     3 END1  2022-05-08
#>  4 2019-05-19     4 END1  2019-05-19
#>  5 2022-09-18     5 END1  2022-09-18
#>  6 2022-08-07     6 END1  2022-08-07
#>  7 2022-05-08     7 END1  2022-05-08
#>  8 2024-02-25     8 END1  2024-02-25
#>  9 2022-05-08     9 END1  2022-05-08
#> 10 2022-08-07    10 END1  2022-08-07
#> 11 2019-11-24    11 END1  2019-11-24
#> 12 2019-11-24    12 END1  2019-11-24
#> 13 2023-09-24    13 END1  2023-09-24
#> 14 2022-08-07    14 END1  2022-08-07
#> 15 2022-08-07    15 END1  2022-08-07
#> 16 2020-05-27    17 END3  2020-05-27
#> 17 2020-05-27    18 END3  2020-05-27
#> 18 2020-10-23    19 END3  2020-10-23
#> 19 2024-06-02    20 END2  2024-06-02
#> 20 2022-10-02    21 END1  2022-10-02

Created on 2024-06-13 with reprex v2.1.0

If base R is required, please clarify it, I will remove this answer.

It's ok. In fact your idea is really helpful.

Here's a solution using apply :
sample$match_date <- apply(sample, 1, \(x) names(x[-1][x[-1] %in% x[1]][1]))
sample$match_date
# [1] "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1"
#[11] "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1" "END1" NA     "END3" "END3" "END3" "END2"
#[21] "END1"

We pass the entire dataframe in apply where the first column (x[1]) is the value to compare with rest of the data (x[-1]). Comparison is done using %in% instead of == since it returns FALSE for NA values. The last [1] ensures that it will always return only one column name even if there are multiple dates that match. Additionally, it also helps to return NA when there is no match (like in row 16).
